# Turn-based Alexa Skill

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to dive into building an Alexa skill and I have a specific game in mind that involves the Alexa and the user taking turns counting up. Alexa would begin saying one and the user would then say two. Alexa would in turn make sure the inputted number is correct before outputting the next number. I'm having a hard time understanding where to start. From what I read, it seems like each user input  links to an intent. Is that the only way going about this? Sorry if this question isn't very clear due to my lack of understanding.

Comment: I think currently Intent is the only way to link the user input.

Answer (score 1):

For this example, you can map an intent invocation to AMAZON.NUMBER.  That way no matter what number
a user says will invoke the same intent.

Additionally you can keep track of the user's session using the sessionAttributes and conditionally handle the same intent that way.